# Missing display data in jqGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

As you can see below I have 3 pictures. `(5, 10 and 20 data per page)`. I don't know the reason why in the `10 and 20 per page` the data is missing as picture provided.

[image]

**Code**

```
public JsonResult GetDPS(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string startdate, string enddate, string EmployeeId, string month, string year, int ClassificationId)
    {
        var context = new Entities();
        var _pr = new Repository();
        int _month = Convert.ToInt32(month);
        int _employeeid = Convert.ToInt32(EmployeeId);
        int _year = Convert.ToInt32(year);
        if (_month > 0 && _year > 0)
        {
            DateTime Dstartdate = new DateTime(_year, _month, 1);
            startdate = Dstartdate.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
            enddate = Dstartdate.AddMonths(1).ToShortDateString();
        }
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        var periods = _pr.GetDPSList(Convert.ToDateTime(startdate), Convert.ToDateTime(enddate), _employeeid, ClassificationId);
        int totalRecords = periods.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        var reqs = periods.OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        int i = 0;
        var rowsObj = new object[pageSize > totalRecords ? totalRecords : pageSize];
        foreach (vwDPSPerEmployee req in reqs)
        {
            int rowId = i;
            int DPSHeaderId = Convert.ToInt32(req.DPSHeaderId);
            string DateApplied = req.DateApplied.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string DPSClassification = req.DPSClassificationDesc;
            string StartDate = req.DateFrom.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string EndDate = req.DateTo.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string Departure = req.Departure.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            string Arrival = req.Arrival.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            string Destination = req.Destination;
            string ContactPerson = req.ContactPerson;
            string Purpose = req.Purpose;
            rowsObj[i] = new { id = i, cell = new object[] { rowId, DPSHeaderId, DateApplied, DPSClassification, StartDate, EndDate, DateofDPS, Departure, Arrival, Destination, ContactPerson, Purpose } };
            i++;
        }
        if (totalRecords != 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowsObj.Length; j++)
            {
                if (rowsObj[j] == null)
                { rowsObj[j] = new { id = j, cell = new object[] { j, j, "", "" } }; }
                else { }
            }
        }
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = rowsObj
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Does anyone encounter like this?. Or anyone know about it?. I spend days to solve this issue.

Comment: Please write always which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid (free jqGrid, commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). jqGrid is jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. You should post JavaScript code, which you use. Additionally if you suspect that jqGrid works wrong, you should prepare the demo, which demonstrates the problem. You can use Developer Tools of Chrome/IE or such tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to get JSON data returned from the server. After that one can create the demo, which uses the data without your server.

Answer (score 0):

I Think You should use Sorting on Fileddate(DateApplied) Column .

```
public JsonResult GetDPS(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string startdate, string enddate, string EmployeeId, string month, string year, int ClassificationId)
    {
        var context = new Entities();
        var _pr = new Repository();
        int _month = Convert.ToInt32(month);
        int _employeeid = Convert.ToInt32(EmployeeId);
        int _year = Convert.ToInt32(year);
        if (_month > 0 && _year > 0)
        {
            DateTime Dstartdate = new DateTime(_year, _month, 1);
            startdate = Dstartdate.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
            enddate = Dstartdate.AddMonths(1).ToShortDateString();
        }
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        var periods = _pr.GetDPSList(Convert.ToDateTime(startdate), Convert.ToDateTime(enddate), _employeeid, ClassificationId);
        int totalRecords = periods.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
        var reqs = periods.OrderBy(x=>x.DateApplied).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        int i = 0;
        var rowsObj = new object[pageSize > totalRecords ? totalRecords : pageSize];
        foreach (vwDPSPerEmployee req in reqs)
        {
            int rowId = i;
            int DPSHeaderId = Convert.ToInt32(req.DPSHeaderId);
            string DateApplied = req.DateApplied.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string DPSClassification = req.DPSClassificationDesc;
            string StartDate = req.DateFrom.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string EndDate = req.DateTo.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string Departure = req.Departure.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            string Arrival = req.Arrival.Value.ToShortTimeString();
            string Destination = req.Destination;
            string ContactPerson = req.ContactPerson;
            string Purpose = req.Purpose;
            rowsObj[i] = new { id = i, cell = new object[] { rowId, DPSHeaderId, DateApplied, DPSClassification, StartDate, EndDate, DateofDPS, Departure, Arrival, Destination, ContactPerson, Purpose } };
            i++;
        }
        if (totalRecords != 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowsObj.Length; j++)
            {
                if (rowsObj[j] == null)
                { rowsObj[j] = new { id = j, cell = new object[] { j, j, "", "" } }; }
                else { }
            }
        }
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = rowsObj
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I already test it. As I notice when I'm debugging it. When I didn't use break point the data is replace by another data. As you can see the `8/18/16`. But then I set break point and open the result of `periods and reqs` and find the data. It returns perfectly fine.